# php 5.3 get_class doesn't return class name when typed paremeters are used in constructor

Tags: php, refactoring

In one of my projects I am using doctrine2 where there is an entityManger with entity class names like this:

```
$entityManager->getRepository('\Application\Entity\Book')
```

As you can see this name is inside quotes which makes it difficult to refactor using an IDE.

In php there is a `get_class` method, which I can use the following way to get the name of a specific class:

```
get_class(new somenamespace\someclass);
```

However, this only works if the class has no typed parameters in the constructor:

```
namespace model;

class ClassWithConstructorArguments {

    /**
     * 
     * @param \ArrayObject $arg1
     * @param \ArrayObject $arg2
     */
    function __construct(\ArrayObject $arg1, \ArrayObject $arg2) {

    }

}
```

From what I read is that this function is to get the class-name of an object, however I can't make that object because the constructor expects certain parameters.

So my question is: is there a way to get the class name of a class such as one above?

**Update:**
Since the classes I want to use are generated classes modifying them is not the best option so for now I will create adapter classes like this:

```
namespace Application\Adapter;

class BookAdapter extends \Application\Entity\Book {

    public static function className() {
        return get_parent_class();
    }

}
```

But I am still wondering if there is a better solution because this way I have to create adapter classes for each new entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `get_class` string from the `disable_functions` at **php.ini** file. Or you can use  `__CLASS__` constant within the class.

```
namespace model;

class ClassWithConstructorArguments {

    /**
     * 
     * @param \ArrayObject $arg1
     * @param \ArrayObject $arg2
     */
    function __construct(\ArrayObject $arg1, \ArrayObject $arg2) {

    }

    public function getClass() {

        return __CLASS__;
    }

}

$obj = new ClassWithConstructorArguments(/* ... */)
echo $obj->getClass();
```

Comment: So the only way is to make a function inside the classes I want to use? Which would be a static function in my case since I don't want the constructor to be called.

Comment: By the way: I don't understand how the disabled functions in php.ini has to do with the `get_class` function since it already works although not the way I expected it to be working.

Comment: Yes, `static` function will work too, if you don't want use constructor. I don't see other way in this case. If you are the autor of this class - I don't think that it's a problem to add one method to class.

Comment: Or if you are using `ClassWithConstructorArguments` as third-party libraries, you can extends `ClassWithConstructorArguments` class by other your class, in which add this `public static function getClass()` method and call them

Comment: The problem is that the classes I want to use are entity classes which I generate from a database using the doctrine 2 script. Which means the getClass function will be removed each time I execute that script.

Comment: Are you tested it? As I know doctrine do not remove your methods when you run `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle`. So your method don't removed. And you can extends this class by your own with this method at last, which don't modified by doctrine.

Comment: All my entities are generated from a database not for a database so I have code like this: `doctrine-module orm:convert-mapping --namespace=Application\Entity\ --from-database annotation module\Application\src --force`

Comment: So I recommended you to extends this class `ClassWithConstructorArguments` by your own with this method, which don't modified by doctrine.

Comment: I guess I have to accept the answer since I can't find a better one!